# on windows, where does python's socket.getfqdn() pull from?

Tags: python

on Windows, does anyone know the ultimate source of the data that is returned by socket.getfqdn()?  I have a system where I expect the FQDN to be "foo.bar.baz.example.com", and getfqdn() is returning ".snafu.example.com"

Comment: probably the windows dns system. check hosts, then check dns servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`socket.getfqdn()` calls either

- [`gethostname()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms738527(v=vs.85).aspx)
- or resolves the name using [`gethostbyaddr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms738521(v=vs.85).aspx) for `getfqdn(name)`.

For `gethostbyaddr()` it picks the first name with a `.` in the name and defaults to the host's name if no dotted name could be found. See the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/642bebc901ea780e40e0295bb9c90a34c2f34503/Lib/socket.py#L650).

Name resolution order [on Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172218) is:

1. own name
2. hosts file if exists
3. DNS
4. NetBIOS (order changeable, sometimes disabled)

Comment: I always love it when I see people use the source!

Comment: @WayneWerner Most of the Python libraries are a really good read, too. Not something I can say about other software.

Comment: Indeed. Almost any Python question I have at this point is something that is answered by looking at the source :) (or `dis.dis()`)